# TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'RNGestureHandlerModule.default.Direction')

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, node-modules

I have problem with module `'react-navigation-stack'` I've written the same code from https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation#react-navigation.
Platform: Android. OS: ubuntu

```
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import SearchScreen from './scr/screen/SearchScreen';

const navigator = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Search: SearchScreen
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'Search',
        defaultNavigationOptions: {
            title: 'App'
        }
    }
);
const App = createAppContainer(navigator);
export default App;
```

[image]

Comment: could you share dependencies on your package.json?

Comment: @DragonWhite "dependencies": {
    "jetifier": "^1.6.4",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3"
  },

Comment: All errors, code, and data must be embedded as text, not pics. 1) users should be able to chippy paste (error messages, etc) into their search engines, or editors to efficiently help you, and without introducing typos. 2) pics can be difficult to read text in, especially on mobile devices, and also take more data on mobile connections. Please read topics on asking on the SO help section: https://StackOverflow.com/help for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How I have solved the `RNGestureHandlerModule.default.Direction` error:

1. be sure that you put that import at the top of your entry point script file

   ```
   import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
   ```
2. clean Gradle

   ```
   cd ./android && ./gradlew clean && cd ..
   ```
3. start the Android app with

   ```
   react-native run-android --verbose
   ```

and be sure this you see that line in bundler logs:

```
> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
```

if you do not see it it looks like bundle did not link react-native-gesture-handler to your app.

Especially check 1) if you have a **monorepo** with a mobile version index.js|tsx in one package and the whole app in another - import should be added at the top of the mobile entry point script.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add **curly braces** around **createStackNavigator** like so:

> { createStackNavigator }

Comment: sorry my bad, there are curly braces. But same error(

Comment: @bekanur98 Ok, no worries, did you install **react-native-gesture-handler** package?

Comment: yeah. ```npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler``` after that ```react-native link```

Comment: @bekanur98 it seems that it isn't linked correctly, can you check it manually?

Comment: @bekanur98 which version are you using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202727/discussion-between-bekanur98-and-j-doe).

Comment: @LeriGogsadze Hi Leri, hope you are good. Is it possible to scan credit card details using expo CLI?

Answer (score 0):

this is the fixed app.
https://snack.expo.io/@whitedragon226/stackdemo

***Fixed lines***

```
import React from 'react';
```

and add some dependencies

```
...
    "react-native-screens": "^1.0.0-alpha",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.0.0"
```

[this doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html#installing-dependencies-into-a-bare-react-native-project) is may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's bug or I don't know. After all of action from https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html You need reinstall application in your device. I hope it's work for you.