# how to solve "null is not object(evaluating RNGestureHandlerModule.default.direction" in react native 5.0

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5

I have installed all the dependencies according to the react navigation docs.. when I copied code from docs this error occurs..
my dependencies are

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.0.5",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.0.5",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^3.6.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.0.0-beta.7"
  },
```

Comment: In which os ? Android or iOS ?

Comment: Who has that problem in Android try to check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61218793/6152462

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION FOR ANDROID**

From your project root folder run :

1. `cd android`
2. `./gradlew clean`
3. run project `react-native run-android`

**SOLUTION FOR IOS**

From your project root folder run :

5. `cd ios`
6. `pod install`
7. run project `react-native run-ios`

**If these solutions didn't work remove your `node_modules` folder and re-install using `npm install`**

***NOTE :***

- Do not link packages using react-native link since you are using RN 0.60 >