# TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating’_RNGestureHandlerModule.default.Direction’)

Tags: reactjs, navigation, react-native, react-navigation

After running the following code of react-native in mobile it is showing error. Error is:

> "TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating’_RNGestureHandlerModule.default.Direction’)".

I had installed all the libraries needed to run the app.
Please help me to solve my error. Code is :

App.js

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import HomeScreen from './modules/HomeScreen';
import SecondScreen from './modules/SecondScreen';
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
function App() {
return (
<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator>

    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />

    <Stack.Screen name="Second" component={SecondScreen} />

  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
);
}

export default App;
```

HomeScreen.js:

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
navigateToScreen=()=>{
navigation.navigate('Second');
}
return (
<View style={styles.MainContainer}>
  <Text style={styles.text}> Home Screen </Text>
  <Button onPress={this.navigateToScreen} title="Navigate To Second Screen" /> 
</View>
);
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
MainContainer: {
flex: 1,
justifyContent: 'center',
alignItems: 'center'
},

text: {
textAlign: 'center',
margin: 18,
fontSize: 24,
fontWeight: "200",
},
});
export default HomeScreen ;
```

SecondScreen.js

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
function SecondScreen() {
return (
<View style={styles.MainContainer}>
  <Text style={styles.text}> Second Screen </Text>
</View>
);
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
MainContainer: {
flex: 1,
justifyContent: 'center',
alignItems: 'center'
},
text: {
textAlign: 'center',
fontSize: 24,
fontWeight: "200",
},
});
export default SecondScreen;
```

Comment: Did you restart your app? It seems like the code can't reach the native modules (Java code), try to build your app and install it again

Comment: It worked. Thanks alot :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58955199/typeerror-null-is-not-an-object-evaluating-rngesturehandlermodule-default-dir this can help you. And I have fixed this bug after i follow this.